# Cant Run Image as Container

Tags: docker, dockerfile, node-modules

I have successfully created the image of the project. But when I want to run this image as a container, I get the following error

```
> react-the-complete-guide@0.1.0 start
> react-scripts start

sh: react-scripts: not found
```

My docker file is like that :

```
FROM node:16.14-alpine3.14 

WORKDIR /frontend

COPY package.json .

RUN npm install -g npm@8.12.1

COPY . .

EXPOSE 3000

CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

The Package.json file is like that :

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
     .
     .
     .

  }
```

I deleted node_module and tried it that way, but it didn't work, I did many things like this, but it doesn't work. I would be pleased if you could help.

Comment: Why are you installing a specific npm anyway?

Comment: Because first ı tried just “Run npm install “ but it also didnt work. After searching a lot, ı installed specific npm but didnt changed anything

Answer (score 1):

You're not installing the dependencies from package.json. Add `RUN npm install` like this

```
FROM node:16.14-alpine3.14 

WORKDIR /frontend

COPY package.json .

RUN npm install -g npm@8.12.1
RUN npm install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 3000

CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

Comment: I have used spesific Npm because typical Run npm install doesnt work it is throwing the same error